# Values from JSON encode array are not passing to the variables

Tags: php, mysql

I have issue that i am not able to retrieve values from the json array. Below is the code which i have written.

```
$receiver_data=$_POST['array'];

$new_array=json_decode($receiver_data,true);

foreach($new_array as $row)
{
    $m_id='".$row["m_id"]."'; 
    $u_id='".$row["u_id"]."';
    break;
}

$query = "DELETE FROM `squads` WHERE m_id=? AND u_id=? ";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $m_id,$u_id);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: In your loop `'".$row["m_id"]."'` with single quotes is a literal value (including the variable names,quotes etc.).  Juts use `$row["m_id"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need  quote for assignments
the data binging convert properly the type (ss)

```
$receiver_data=$_POST['array'];

$new_array=json_decode($receiver_data,true);

foreach($new_array as $row)
{
    $m_id= $row["m_id"] ; 
    $u_id=$row["u_id"];
    break;
}

$query = "DELETE FROM `squads` WHERE m_id=? AND u_id=? ";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $m_id,$u_id);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();
```

and if you want delete all the rows  remove break  and add  delete code in loop

```
$receiver_data=$_POST['array'];

$new_array=json_decode($receiver_data,true);

$query = "DELETE FROM `squads` WHERE m_id=? AND u_id=? ";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);

foreach($new_array as $row)
{
    $m_id= $row["m_id"] ; 
    $u_id=$row["u_id"];
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $m_id,$u_id);
    $stmt->execute();

}

$stmt->close();
```

or for avoid the loop and delete just the first

```
$receiver_data=$_POST['array'];

$new_array=json_decode($receiver_data,true);
$m_id= new_array[0]["m_id"] ; 
$u_id=new_array[0]["u_id"];

$query = "DELETE FROM `squads` WHERE m_id=? AND u_id=? ";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $m_id,$u_id);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Why would you put the `prepare()` etc. in the loop?

Comment: @NigelRen   answer  updated (. i was  editing .. the  code .. ..doing others too)

Comment: What if we only want to delete only very first row in JSON array? @scaisEdge

Comment: then just assign the value of the first rows  (you could avoid the loop and break)

Comment: answer updated  without loop

Comment: @scaisEdge thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: @JahanzaibNiazi   .. you are welcome ... i hope is all clear now